# Which motor driver to use with a DC gear-box motor?

Tags: motor, integrated-circuit

I have this [motor](http://keskinlerelektronik.com.tr/eng/icerik/2/KGA25RP.html) (a "PMDC Spur Gear Motor/KGA25RP")

I am not sure if something like L298 will work with it since it is a DC gear-box motor. What kind of driver should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [L298](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l298.pdf) H bridge IC has a maximum supply voltage of 50 V and a maximum continous current (per output channel) of 2 A, so it will work with every subtype of your motor: the highest current motor is rated for 0.4 A at 12 V, well in the range of the H bridge, and the highest voltage motors are rated 24 V, half of the maximum voltage of the L298.

The inclusion of gears in the motor assembly is completely irrelevant to the *electrical* characteristics of the motor.